# Add content in cpt archive page

Tags: hooks, custom-post-type-archives

I am trying to add some custom content hooked into custom post type archive page but I can't. I have already achieved it in single page with:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'yourprefix_add_to_content' );
```

and `is_singular(cpt)` and then append some content, but when I try to do something similar to archive page with `is_post_type_archive('cpt')` it just doesn't work. Which is the right hook and function to do that?

Comment: Have you created a template for your CPT archive?  Using something like `{post-type}-archive.php` would give you complete control over the archive page.  I realize this does not answer your question but thought you might be unaware of this template option. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am aware of this option but right now I cannot do that and I am trying some kind of hook to get the full content of the page and append some text in it.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161078/45202

Comment: Are you replacing the main query with a custom query via `get_posts`/`WP_Query`/`query_posts` to change what gets shown?

Comment: No actually, I just created a cpt with register_post_type. I am making a very simple approach for a client with just some css and I wanted to add a custom text before the_loop of the post types but it seems that I must make a custom template with {post-type}-archive.php as jdm suggested before.